# Im working on a payment gateway using React js and C# .net, I want to get the response from iFrame

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net

I'm working on a payment gateway(PTT sanal pos) using React js and C# asp.net. I've followed the documentation and found that I'm supposed to put an iFrame inside my component to make the payment as show below:

```
<iframe src={`https://aeo.ptt.gov.tr/api/Payment/threeDSecure/${code}`} height="900px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Actually as a first step I have made a POST request to a url my clientId, pass, etc.. and a **CallBackURL** that the gateway will post to it the data when payment is done.

I didn't get through this step, Do I have any method to get the data from iFrame or should I send the data to backend by using CallBackURL.

I'm getting the response data also from the payload tab on network tab.

1.step POST request codes:

```
   const clientId = ******
    const ApiUser = "******"
    const rnd = randomGenerator.toString();
    const timestamp = moment().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss");
    const ApiPass = "******"
    const hashString = ApiPass + clientId + ApiUser + rnd + timestamp;
    const hash = SHA512(hashString).toString(enc.Base64);
    const callBackUrl = `${import.meta.env.VITE_API}/tests`
    const Amount = 5000
    const currency = 949

    const data = {
        "clientId": clientId,
        "apiUser": ApiUser,
        "rnd": rnd,
        "timeSpan": timestamp,
        "hash": hash,
        "callbackUrl": callBackUrl,
        "amount": Amount,
        "currency": currency
    }

    const [ThreeDSessionId, SetThreeDSessionId] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        handleSubmit();
    }, []);

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        // Perform API request with form data
        axios.post("https://aeo.ptt.gov.tr/api/Payment/threeDPayment", data).then((res) => {
            if (res.data.ThreeDSessionId) {
                SetThreeDSessionId(res.data.ThreeDSessionId)
            }
        })
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set a callback url then likely after the iFrame completes its process, it will redirect to that callback url with the payload data.

I would follow your own advice and send the data to your backend by passing your backend endpoint as the callback url.

Comment: I've followed the documentation and pass a backend endpoint but I can't access these payload data from my backend I don't know the data type that they are sending